# WKWebView loading html code instead of contents (iOS)

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I am trying to load the following html file: 
`https://dev-attachments-public.clickup.com/d23cdacd-510c-440e-818f-1e0f4d1a10bd/Email.html` into my WKWebView doing the following:

```
let targetURL = NSURL(string: htmlFile)
let webView = WKWebView(frame: paddingView.bounds)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: targetURL as URL)
webView.load(request as URLRequest)
```

However, it only loads the code:

[image]

I'm not sure why this is occurring.  Do I need to download this file locally then display it?

Comment: This html file does not begin with html tag, that is why it is not showing up as a webpage on webView in iOS

Comment: i had scrolled down the wkwebiew a little prior to taking the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [AnyObject]
let filePath: String = "\(paths[0])/\("index.html")"

if let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: htmlFile) {

    do {
        let urlData: NSData = try NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
        urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)))

    } catch {
        print("Error:  Could not fetch fetchedResultsController")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that following that link on desktop also causes the file to be downloaded instead of displayed in a web browser. Looking at the headers for the request, your server is currently sending its `Content-Type` as `application/octet-stream`. This tells browsers (such as `WKWebView`) that this file is raw data and should be downloaded, displayed, and treated as such. Instead, you should send your `Content-Type` header as `text/html`, which tells browsers that it should render and display the HTML as a webpage. Furthermore, you should probably remove the `Content-Disposition` header to allow it to be its default of displaying inline as a webpage